# On and off variables for Debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, variables

I forgot what these kinds of variables are called so I can't search for them.

it is declared something like this `private static string sampleVariable=":8080"` and there are special characters on the right of it where the coder will just type `true` or `false` before terminating the line of code with `;` without any other code being implemented besides that line

Does anyone have an idea? I remember seeing this kind of sniplet of code in debugging mode during my internship

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: please provide more context.

Comment: Do you mean the conditional operator expression ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the conditional operator expession.

Take at look at this for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx